# how to create a device specific app in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to create an app which is specific to the device type.Say my app should work only on  iPhone but not on iPad or iPod even if it (the app) has common features.

Comment: Why? You don't like your apps getting on the store?

Comment: no but my manager has asked me to do so.....

Comment: If it's just an exercise then ask `UIDevice` its model, and if it's `iPhone` pass, anything else, `abort()`. But that's still silly, smack your manager for the rest of us, I'm too far away to do it myself.

Comment: simply UIDevice ==iPhone

Comment: I agree that your manager needs to be smacked.  Do that first.

Comment: What's the point?  No app that won't run on the iPad will make it to the app store so it's pointless to put effort into deliberately crippling it.

Answer (score 1):

[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]; would give you the current device model.

Now, compare strings with the isEqualToString: rather than using the comparison operator.

Once done, you should write the functionality that you want to run, after doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is for App Store distribution you may be able to use the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key of Info.plist to produce a sufficiently restrictive set of requirements. Make this entry a dictionary and then for example setting a `telephony=false` value would exclude phone devices, `still-camera=false` value would exclude (current) iPads etc.  The iTunes/App Store will then not allow a user to install the app on an unsupported device